# Create UITableView like instagram to display name, image and text

Tags: swift, uitableview

how can i create a `UITableView` like `Instagram` as?
I am thinking something like, each `cell` contains:

Cell 1:

> Uploader Name
>
> Image
>
> Image Text

Cell 2:

> Uploader Name
>
> Image
>
> Image Text

And so it goes on... Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is create a subclass of UITableViewCell. There is a good tutorial on that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfZGKx4BYVU

After properly creating the UITableViewCell subclass, you need to set it up as a reusable cell on your UITableView. You can do that by selecting a prototype cell in the storyboard and assigning your custom class to it.

I believe the youtube link above explain the whole process.

Comment: If you want an exemple written in Swift, check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG_AMY_gSDQ

Comment: I will take a look at it. I am having my project connected to Parse.com, and its a instagram look-a-like application, so i am going to load the users name, photo and the photo text to UITableView.

Comment: Only that it does not do exactly what i want. I want the Name, photo and text on top of each other, not on the side of each other, if you understand.. :)

Comment: I see, but if you know how to put it side by side, you just need to put it on top of each other. I've did something similar with Parse. Don't forget to load the data from Parse before initializing the cells.

Comment: How to i load it? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012101/loading-images-from-parse-com/32014715#32014715

Answer (score 0):

The function below queries the image from a Parse database. If you do not know how to use Parse, check www.parse.com. They have a lot of tutorials.

```
func queryImageDataInBackgroundForFile(file: PFFile, AndHandleWith handler: (data: NSData) -> ()) {
        file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if data != nil {
                    handler(data: data!)
                }
            } else {
                println("ERROR -> ParseDAO.queryImageDataInBackgroundForFile")
            }
        }
    }
```

You would put inside the UITableViewDelegate method that loads the cells the following call to the function:

```
parseDAO.queryImageDataInBackgroundForFile(place.coverImageFile, AndHandleWith: { (data) -> () in
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        })
```

If you are loading the image from a local assets file you can do the following

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "name of your image file")
```