# Loading images from parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, sdwebimage

This is my saving image to parse:

```
func uploadPost(){
        var imageText = self.imageText.text

        if (imageView.image == nil){
            println("No image uploaded")
        }
        else{
            var posts = PFObject(className: "Posts")
            posts["imageText"] = imageText
            posts["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    //**Success saving, now save image.**//

                    // Create an image data
                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)
                    // Create a parse file to store in cloud
                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload_image.png", data: imageData)
                    posts["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
                    posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            // Take user home
                            println("Data uploaded")
                        }
                        else{
                            println(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
                else{
                    println(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

How can I load the images from parse? This is how my Parse.com "Posts" data looks like: [image]

Any suggestions?

I think maybe something like using this:

```
self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, completed: block)
```

But I don´t know how I get the URL. And what if the images has different names?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
let imageFile = pfObject["imageFile"] as? PFFile
    if imageFile != nil{
        imageFile!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                }
             }
         }
     }
```

Where pfObject is the reference to your object. There are other ways you could check for a nil value, but this should work.

As long as you have a reference to the correct object (which you can get via a query for objectId) then you should only need the name of the column the image is file is stored in and not the image file itself.

Comment: Hm, how should i fix the "Use of unresolved identifier 'pfObject'" error?

Comment: @Eri-Sklii "pfObject" should just be the reference to the object you're trying to get the image from. In your case it looks like it might be "posts"

Comment: Looks like your query is wrong. You're comparing a string to a file, so you're never going to get a match. How are you intending to match an image with a cell? Your query by default will give you every post object, and you need to be able to refine the query to get exactly what you're looking for, and since I don't know what that is, I'm not sure what to tell you.